# Which is better - AWS S3 or EBS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ebs

I am trying to create a system where users can upload their data (audio, text) which can run into around 200 MB per user. I am trying to figure out what is the best way to go ahead - using S3 or EBS.

Here's what I have found till now based on my research

**EBS advantage**

- lower latency with less variation
- fast directory listing and searching
- no consistency delays

**S3 advantages**

- For a streaming use case, S3 may be a better choice
- provides a web services interface for storing and retrieving data
- can be secured with tokens

**EBS Disadvantage**

- may fail and lose their data
- data should be backed to prevent data loss

**S3 Disadvantage**

- Has low directory listing and searching
- higher latency
- there may be a delay in writes appearing in the system

My conclusion - EBS is better for fast response and S3 for durability. I am looking into the possibility of backing up data with Glacier.

So which one should I use - EBS or S3?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use s3.. you won't be able to scale out with EBS since it can only be mounted on a single server. With s3 you can upload from multiple servers.

Plus s3 never goes down.. ebs has been known to have really epic failures. Even data loss.

Comment: EBS can most certainly be scaled. They're just disk drives - something like Gluster allows scale-out and data redundancy.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that S3 is down right now and has been for over an hour.